# I need some material about Poisson disk sampling

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, sampling

I'm looking for some material to gain a better understanding about Poisson disk sampling. Specifically I would like to understand how a point is generated, and since I'm using it to generate points inside a rectangular 2D area, I'd like to gain knowledge about what's the probability distribution from which the points are sampled (e.g. how close is it to be uniform? Does any point share the same probability to be selected? I would be tempted to say that each point has a null probability to be selected, in which case I'm interested in the probability density function of the distribution from where samples are taken).

I searched online a bit and unfortunately the web world seemed to me to be pretty avid of material about it. All I could find was papers discussing algorithmic strategies to efficiently implement it on a computer. I'm more interested in the mathematical aspect of it as of now.

Any resource about the topic is definitely appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need a definition.  Since something like "points are independently uniformly distributed except that they are a minimum distance apart" is not meaningful, you will probably use an algorithm to choose points, and the mathematics will depend on the algorithm chosen as well as the number of points and minimum distance.  I suspect you will get faster results by simulation.

Comment: Hi, the algorithm for generating a new point must be just something like this: if the region is $[x_0,x_1]\times[y_0,y_1]$  then I generate a random $x_0\leq x\leq x_1$ and  $y_0\leq y\leq y_1$, then starting from that generate a random angle in $[0,2\pi]$ and a radius between $r$ and $2r$ if $r$ is the minimum distance parameter.

Comment: It might be, though that can produce overlaps once you have three or more points, and there are other algorithms which will produce other patterns